# Oracle APEX 5 nested Label not selecting input

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have recently upgraded to Oracle APEX 5 and had a strange issue with some of the inputs not being selected.

I narrowed it down to controls that were nested within a label.

It seems that if there is no 'for' attribute and 'id' on the control it fails.

```
//This will not check the input
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>This is a test</span></label>
```

so I can manually change it to this to prove it works.

```
<label for="chkTest"><input id="chkTest" type="checkbox"><span>This is a test</span></label>
```

However if you save the above html into a file and load it , both will work.

I then noticed in some older apps in apex 4 the inputs work and they are simply wrapped in a label element....

Comment: You should really post your issues with migrations on the Oracle APEX OTN forums. The devs are active there and your problem will most likely actually be taken a look at, certainly with how fresh apex 5 is and how they'd like to take stock of issues. This question is really more about support, and the pool of users on SO for apex is far too small for this. https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/application_express

Comment: Thanks for feedback have done https://community.oracle.com/thread/3720966 guess it cant hurt being in both places.

Comment: It doesn't per se, but only posting it here won't give you the exposure you'll require. This problem is likely to go back-and-forth several times in order to try and determine the problems and SO isn't structured as such.